# Rails 4 - Heroku, precompile assets failed

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, precompile

I'm having a problem with assets loading in Heroku and haven't been able to resolve this issue on my own. Right now, I am unable to get assets to load on my app in Heroku.

I was told that I needed to precompile my assets locally. The only way I could get this to work was by changing `= require_self` and `= require_tree .` in application.css manifest to `@import`. From there I was able to run `rake assets:precompile`, but no styles loaded on Heroku or locally. I switched things back and now styles show up locally, but I can no longer push to heroku. I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...AwesomeEotPath:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " 'fontawesome-..."
(in /tmp/build/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):7153
```

Comment: I think I answered your other Q - the best thing will be to post your `Gemfile` & other dependencies to give us a view of what files are being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message you posted there is a syntax error in your sass file.  Is there a comma after that line around 7152 or 7153? Or maybe " ; " instead of " : " ?

Comment: Yep, there was an error in the sass file that the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem generated. Thanks!